# Getaround to avoid error if empty value in PDO INSERT query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Below is the simple script to allow users to add an `<a href> tag` to their list.

If there's no `<a href> tag`, then `$author_id` is empty.

The first query works fine, the 2nd doesn't if $author_id is empty.

How can i avoid getting an error if it's empty?  (i'm sure I'm overthinking

```
$content = $_POST['book_title'];
preg_match_all('/@\w+/is', $content, $matches);
foreach ($matches[0] as $v) {
    $name = substr($v, 1, strlen($v));
    $sql = "SELECT id, author FROM users WHERE author like '%{$name}%' LIMIT 1";
    $result = query($sql);
      if($result[0]['author']) {
       $author = $result[0]['author'];
       $author_id = $result[0]['id'];
       $content = str_replace($v, "<a href='/$author'>$v</a>",$content);

--->
//if i put $sql query here, $bookid doesn't exist yet
      }
}

    // works fine
$insert=$sth->con->prepare("INSERT INTO booklist (userid, bookid, book) VALUES (?,'', ?)");
$insert->bindParam(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
$insert->bindParam(2, $content, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
$insert->execute();

    // when $author_id is empty, it doesn't work
$sql=$sth->con->prepare("INSERT INTO notifications (notifid, user, author, type, bookid) VALUES ('',?, ?,'3',LAST_INSERT_ID())");
$sql->bindParam(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
$sql->bindParam(2, $author_id, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
$sql->execute();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is `$author_id` an empty string, or is it undefined?

Comment: Your variables will only contain the values from the last successful query in the `foreach` loop. Is that what you want?

Comment: @barmar, yes, that's what I want. And if `($result[0]['author'])` doesn't return any results, then $author_id should be saved as 0 in the DB.

Comment: The problem is that if you try to store an undefined variable, it's trying to set the database column to NULL. My guess is that your schema has `NOT NULL` for the `author_id` column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$author_id is not empty in your case, it is undefined, define $author_id before foreach statement as:

```
$author_id = '';
foreach ($matches...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i'm not sure to understand. To define $author_id I need to query the DB based on $name . And If $name comes before `foreach ($matches[0] as $v)`, I get an undefined variable error.

Comment: @ChHr define variable in this case mean - store "default" value if you didn't find proper one, $name variable depends on $v - which is defined only inside loop, you cannot define it outside

Answer (score 1):

you need to define your $author_id first

```
author_id = null;
```

and than do a foreach loop